# Remove or hiding a text

Tags: javascript, html

I am new in JavaScript, and I am learning but now I am facing a little problem that I don't know how to solve, this is my code so far...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>algo</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function ShowMenu(control, e) {
        var posx = e.clientX + 'px';
        var posy = e.clientY + 'px';
        document.getElementById(control).style.position = 'absolute';
        document.getElementById(control).style.display = 'inline';
        document.getElementById(control).style.left = posx;
        document.getElementById(control).style.top = posy;
        var jqContext = '#' + control;
    }

    function HideMenu(control) {

        document.getElementById(control).style.display = 'none';

    }


   </script>
   </head>

<body onclick="HideMenu('contextMenu');" oncontextmenu="return false">
<p onmousedown="HideMenu('contextMenu');"
      onmouseup="HideMenu('contextMenu');"
      oncontextmenu="ShowMenu('contextMenu',event);"
      class="detailItem">
Right Click Here Item: 1
    </p>
     <p onmousedown="HideMenu('contextMenu');"
      onmouseup="HideMenu('contextMenu');"
    oncontextmenu="ShowMenu('contextMenu',event);"
     class="detailItem">
Right Click Here Item: 2
    </p>
   <p onmousedown="HideMenu('contextMenu');"
      onmouseup="HideMenu('contextMenu');"
    oncontextmenu="ShowMenu('contextMenu',event);"
     class="detailItem">
Right Click Here Item: 3
    </p>
<br />
<br />


<div style="display:none; "   id="contextMenu">
    <table  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
        style="border: thin solid #808080; cursor: default;" width="100px" 
        bgcolor="White">
        <tr>
            <td >
                <div onclick="javascript:alert('You Clicked '+this.innerHTML);"                                                      onmouseup="ShowMenu('contextMenu','none',event);" class="ContextItem">View</div>
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >
            <div onclick="javascript:alert('You Clicked '+this.innerHTML);" onmouseup="ShowMenu('contextMenu','none',event);"  class="ContextItem">Restore</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >
                <div onclick="javascript:alert('You Clicked '+this.innerHTML);" onmouseup="ShowMenu('contextMenu','none',event);"  class="ContextItem">Delete</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>


   </body>
   </html>
```

and the output is...

```
Right Click Here Item: 1

Right Click Here Item: 2

Right Click Here Item: 3
```

Until now, the code deactivates the default context menu of the right mouse, an when you click the right mouse over one line of text it displays a context menu that contains, view, restore and delete.
  Now what I want to do, is that when I click over delete in the context menu, it should delete or hide the line of text on which I did the right click and then re-display that line when I click to restore. I had checked several tutorials but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? I see none.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you plan to click on an element `restore` if that element is hidden :D